# Android ViewPager performance on Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: android, performance, tabs, android-viewpager, galaxy

I have an application which uses Android ViewPager (7 views, pretty complex with images and animations). This application runs fantastically on my Asus Eee Pad. It is just gorgeous.

I also have a Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 which almost can not run the app... despite it's brand new and theoretically more powerfull than my EEE Pad. I would like to mention both terminals run Android 4.0.3 and their screen size is identical (1280x800). Application runs in landscape mode.

The application does not use sql, or internet access, just animations on different views and the swipe effect of the ViewPager.

I checked I think everything, from heap, from lint, from basically all the available tools for  profiling but nothing seems to improve my UI performance on the Galaxy Tab 2... I wonder if there isn't some difference in the hardware finally, where the ASUS will use GPU to render the UI and the Galaxy Tab 2 its CPU...

I was wondering finally, if any of you, noticed some similar issues on Galaxy Tab or other tablets when comparing your app behaviors on multiple targets...

Cheers!
Paul

**--- added September 6th ---**

Well, it seems that, despite the Galaxy tablet should use hardware acceleration, it does not. When I am forcing each xml layout with `android:layerType="hardware"` and

```
v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
     ObjectAnimator oaAlpha = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha",0f, 1f);
```

it works finally better... even if it is not as smooth as on the Asus one

Comment: I **think** this question would be more suitable for android enthusiasts than for Stackoverflow, because it seems more like it is a performance problem

Comment: I have to say you are right... unless, there is an option activated on the Asus which is not on the Galaxy... May be somebody found it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I discovered - and this is really odd - that the performance issue was created by the fact that the font size was too high !?!

It was a sad experience... but for some stupid reason the Galaxy Tab 2.0 was having major issues rendering texts written with big sized letters. And it is related to the Galaxy Tabs (so I imagine hardware) because  I tried with So just redesign your app with smaller fonts and don't forget to complain to Samsung.